# I m trying to make 3 dependent drop-down validation lists but I have problem with 3rd one. Got 2 of them but not 3rd one

Tags: vba, excel-formula, drop-down-menu

So I have list like this.

Problems
Cellphones
Laptops
Monitors

When you choose one of those above I need drop menu to offer me specs for that piece.

Under cellphones I have: Sony, Samsung, Apple
Under laptop I have: Toshiba, HP, Lenovo,
Under monitors I have: Samsung, Dell,

So I connected with indirect function when you choose one of problems to give you option to choose next step. Example if I choose under problems Cellphones, second drop menu will offer me to choose sony samsung or apple.

So now comes my problem. 
Last drop menu that I have is models: 
Sony has xperia Z2, xperia Z3
Samsung has S10, S10 plus, S20
Apple has: Iphone X, Iphone 11, Iphone 9

Toshiba has Satellite 1800. Satellite pro 400
HP has Elitebook, Spectre
Lenove has thinkpad yoga, thinkpad extreme

Monitors 
Samsung has G7, G8, G9
Lenovo has LT2452, LT2323

Can someone assist me how to connect 3rd drop down list? 
So what I need is example: After you choose cellphone, 2nd drop down should offer you samsung, sony or apple. If you choose samsung, 3rd drop down should offer you only S10, S10 plus, S20

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do the same thing you did for the first one. For each unique set of values, you will need a corresponding region of values in a named range. You will need to create a named range (like one called `Sumsung`) and make sure all the appropriate values are stored in that named range. Then just use indirect

Comment: Write a separate procedure for 3rd drop down using select case statements.

Comment: https://www.contextures.com/exceldependentdropdownsetup.html is all you need